# Linked list: While fast and fast.next

Tags: python, linked-list

I am learning the following code for Middle of Linked List:

```
class Solution(object):
    def middleNode(self, head):
        """
        :type head: ListNode
        :rtype: ListNode
        """
        slow = fast = head
        while fast and fast.next:
            slow = slow.next
            fast = fast.next.next
        return slow
```

I noticed that if I use "while fast.next" instead of "while fast and fast.next" for the loop, I got the same results. May I ask why I should use both fast and fast.next to stop the while loop? From my understanding, if fast.next is None, fast is always none, is this correct?

Thank you!

Comment: Hint: Try running `fast=None; print(fast.next)`. What do you think is the result?

Comment: This will break if you have an even number of nodes in the list.

Comment: Since you access fast.next.next, you must check if `fast.next` is a valid value( non Null).

Answer (score 3):

> I noticed that if I use `while fast.next` instead of `while fast and fast.next` for the loop, I got the same results.

This will work for input lists that have an *odd* number of nodes, but it will fail withe input lists that have an *even* number of nodes -- the trivial example being an empty list (with 0 nodes).

> May I ask why I should use both `fast and fast.next` to stop the while loop?

In each iteration a pair of nodes is traversed, so in the case of an *even* number of nodes, there will come a situation where `fast` is `None` at the moment the `while` condition is evaluated. If you then only check `fast.next` -- without first ensuring that `fast` is really a node -- it will raise an error, as this really means you're doing `None.next` which of course doesn't work.

> From my understanding, if `fast.next is None`, `fast` is always none, is this correct?

No, this is not correct. If `fast.next is None` then this implies that `fast` is a **node** with a `next` attribute, so certainly `fast` is then not `None`. But `fast.next` can produce an error when `fast is None`. It is for that reason that before evaluating `fast.next` one must be sure that `fast` is a node and not `None`.

If the condition is `fast and fast.next` and it happens that `fast` is `None` then the evaluation will short-circuit and `fast.next` will not be evaluated at all (and that's what you want to avoid an error). This is because the `and` operation is already sure to evaluate to a falsy value when the left-side operand (`fast`) has been evaluated to be `None`.

Answer (score 1):

As you traverse the linked list, and have a fast pointer that advances to the current node's next to next node, you have to make that check. Since the `last node` will have `None` (null) value for its `next` member variable, and if accessed simply as fast.next.next it leads to null pointer exception(NPE). To avoid it, your loop condition must be as you have it right now.

Answer (score -1):

When the number of linked lists you are traversing is odd, in the last conditional judgment, fast points to NULL at this time, then judging fast->next will cause a program error.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution however I don't see any added value to the top answer by trincot or even the comments under the question alone.